# Java SWT StyleRange

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

I am trying to highlight Java syntax using `StyleRange`s in SWT `StyledText` boxes. Here is the relevant code.

```
String code = text.getText();
int fromIndex = 0;
String keyword = "public";

if(code.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())){
    System.out.println("Match found");
    Shell shell = text.getShell();
    Display display = shell.getDisplay();
    System.out.println("Got shell and display...");
    Color orange = new Color(display, 255, 127, 0);
    int index = code.indexOf(keyword, fromIndex);
    int length = keyword.length();
    StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange(0, 22, orange, null,SWT.BOLD);
    text.setStyleRange(styleRange);

    System.out.println("colored...");
    fromIndex = index;
}
```

but the `StyleRange`s do nothing? Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: If i use this new code
 `private void Color_Code(StyledText text) {

```
    Shell shell = this.getShell();
    Display display = shell.getDisplay();

    String[] lines = text.getText().split("\\n");

    String keyWord = "public";
    Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);

    int offset = 0;
    for (String line : lines)
    {
        int index = line.indexOf(keyWord);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            StyleRange range = new StyleRange(index + offset, keyWord.length(), red, null, SWT.BOLD);
            text.setStyleRange(range);
        }

        offset += line.length() + 1; // +1 for the newline character
    }
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}`
```

Tree population code: `private void Populate_Method_Tree(Tree tree) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.size(); i++) {
            int id = SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.get(i).getMCCID();
            TreeItem temp = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.V_SCROLL);
            temp.setText("MCCID: " + id);
            Populate_Drop_Down(id);
        }
    }`

Dropdown Population code:

`protected void Populate_Drop_Down(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.size(); i++) {
                        if (id == SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.get(i).getMCCID()) {
                            ArrayList<String> Method_Names = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.get(i)
                                    .getMethod_Clones().size(); j++) {
                                String name = SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES.get(i)
                                        .getMethod_Clones().get(j).getMethod()
                                        .getFileName();
                                String[] parts = name.split("[\\\\ .]");
                                Method_Names.add(parts[parts.length - 2]
                                        + " "
                                        + Integer
                                                .toString(SampleHandler.f.MCCCLONES
                                                        .get(i).getMethod_Clones()
                                                        .get(j).getMethod()
                                                        .getMethodID()));
                            }
                            String[] Methds = new String[Method_Names.size()];
                            Methds = Method_Names.toArray(Methds);
                            combo.setItems(Methds);
                            combo.setText(Methds[0]);
                            String[] parts = Methds[0].split("[\\s+]");
                            int MID = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                            Fill_Code(MID);
                        }
                    }
    }`

Textbox filling code:

`private void Fill_Code(int MID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < SampleHandler.f.METHODS.size(); i++) {
            if (SampleHandler.f.METHODS.get(i).getMethodID() == MID) {
                text.setText(SampleHandler.f.METHODS.get(i).getCode());
                //Color_Code(text);
            }
        }
    }`

it highlight the word public in my first instance but stops populating my dropdown menu and tree.

Comment: Just a note: Remember to `dispose()` all resources you create yourself, e.g. the `Color`.

Comment: You are setting the first 22 characters of the text to be bold + orange, is that what you want?

Comment: for now i just want to see something get highlighted and bold. i'll fix the length and index after

Comment: @Baz yes thank you. i do remember :)

Comment: There is no tree or dropdown in the code you posted.

Comment: sorry. I posted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be something wrong with your other code. Everything works just fine here.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);

    text.setText("public class Text\n{\n    public static void main(String[] args)\n    {\n        System.out.println(\"Text\");\n    }\n}");

    String[] lines = text.getText().split("\\n");

    String keyWord = "public";
    Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);

    int offset = 0;
    for (String line : lines)
    {
        int index = line.indexOf(keyWord);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            StyleRange range = new StyleRange(index + offset, keyWord.length(), red, null, SWT.BOLD);
            text.setStyleRange(range);
        }

        offset += line.length() + 1; // +1 for the newline character
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried to work with your above suggested solution. But it has changed my output from [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/swrepc.png[/IMG] to [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/fvlq37.png[/IMG].

Comment: @Irtza You'll have to elaborate what exactly it is that doesn't work? I don't know your code, so I can't tell you how you have to modify my code to make it work.

Comment: when i add the code to highlight the syntax. it stops populating my both my tree and drop-down menu and removes the shell's title and description to boot.

Comment: @Irtza Well, then you're not using it right. I can't help you without seeing your code...

Comment: if i mail you the relevant code would you be willing to look it over for me?

Comment: @Irtza I'd rather you post it in the question instead. And please don't post all of your code, just the relevant part.